# Chrome extension reliably close windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my extension I want to open some windows with "thirdparty" urls, i.e. not `chrome-extension://` urls. And I want to reliably close all those windows when extension switchs off.

I can do something like this:

```
let w = window.open('url');
window.onunload = () => w.close();
```

But I will have no such control over this window as that of `chrome.windows.create()`.

But I can't close windows created with `chrome.windows.create()` in such way cause `chrome.windows.remove()` will not work in `window.onunload`.

Now I'm doing this:

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url: ...,
    type: 'popup',
    left: 10000,
    top: 0,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
}, function (w) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(w.tabs[0].id, {
        runAt: 'document_start',
        code: 'setInterval(() => { if (!chrome.runtime) window.close(); }, 1000);'
    });
    ...
});
```

But there is little gap (about 1-2 seconds) between window opening and script injecting, so window still can not be reliably closed.

So is there any way for closing such windows on extension disable?

Comment: You can 1) reduce the interval or 2) open a port using chrome.runtime.connect(), then add an `onDisconnect` listener ([more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect)).

Comment: Why don't you open the window using `chrome.windows.create(....)` ?

Comment: @wOxxOm reduce interval? What interval? There is delay in injection, that's main trouble...

Comment: @Titus that is exactly what I'm doing, but i can't close those windows reliably...

Comment: This interval.. 'setInterval(() => { if (!chrome.runtime) window.close(); }, 1000);' he's saying that if you reduce the interval at which you check, you can shave off a good most of a second.

Comment: @PhillipS guys, this code will not be injected, if ill disable extension within 1-2 seconds interval after window creation, this interval does not matters...

Comment: Can you not get a reference to the window from the chrome.windows.create() callback, and then go window.remove(windowId) to close the window?

Comment: How do you inject it? As a content script? The default timing is document_end but you need to specify [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) explicitly.

Comment: I think I get it now, you want to close a window when the user disables your extension from the **Extensions** page and the problem is that once that is done, you can no longer use the Chrome extension API (cannot insert a content script). Is that true ?

Comment: @wOxxOm read it once again carefully please)

Comment: @Titus yep, that is true. It is possible with `window.create()`, but such window can't be opened minimized and focusless so I'm trying to achieve this with `chrome.windows.create()`... My english is not so good so you can edit my question for other people...

Comment: With `document_start` and a content script declared in manifest.json there can be no delay between the start of page loading and the script injection **by definition of this mode**. If you observe the delay then there's something wrong. Either a bug in Chrome or you inject the script with chrome.tabs.executeScript in an onUpdated callback, which performs wrong checks.

Comment: @wOxxOm okay, there is no delay between loading start and script injection, but delay can be between `chrome.windows.create()` call and passed callback call which means that if window takes some time to open this gap is still exists so...

Comment: That technical internal gap should be so short that you won't be able to notice it, for example 10-100ms. Without seeing the actual way you're injecting the code and organizing the callback (or whatever) I can only suppose you're doing it wrong or there's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm edited, check it pls. Maybe it is not only about window opening but also internet connection and html loading idk...

Comment: Well, let's start by eliminating the possibility of a bug - what happens if you reduce `1000` to something like `50`?